# Grey screen flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a grey screen whenever I try to launch the app (I am using Flutlab. I have enabled Internet permission in Manifest files.) I have also erased Expanded() inside the Widget. Can you please point out what could be causing this issue? Here are the version: 1.0.0+1
and the environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  // Variables
  File? imageFile;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _widthTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _heightTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _focusWidth = FocusNode();
  final _focusHeight = FocusNode();

  /// Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image Picker"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: imageFile == null
                ? Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.00),
                                child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(height: 20.00),
                                      FractionallySizedBox(
                                          widthFactor: 0.8,
                                          heightFactor: 0.4,
                                          child: InkWell(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                _getFromGallery();
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/upload.png')), border: Border.all(width: 1.00, color: Colors.black), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.00)),
                                                  child: Image.file(
                                                    imageFile!,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  )))),
                                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      Form(
                                          key: _formKey,
                                          child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                              widthFactor: 0.2,
                                              heightFactor: 0.4,
                                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                                TextFormField(
                                                    controller: _heightTextController,
                                                    focusNode: _focusHeight,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      hintText: "Height",
                                                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
                                                    )),
                                                SizedBox(height: 8.00),
                                                TextFormField(
                                                    controller: _widthTextController,
                                                    focusNode: _focusWidth,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      hintText: "Width",
                                                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
                                                InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Results');
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/submit.png'))), width: 100, height: 100, child: Container()))
                                              ])))
                                    ])))))
                  ])
                : Container(
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.00),
                                child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                      SizedBox(height: 20.00),
                                      FractionallySizedBox(
                                          widthFactor: 0.8,
                                          heightFactor: 0.4,
                                          child: InkWell(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                _getFromGallery();
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/upload.png')), border: Border.all(width: 1.00, color: Colors.black), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.00)),
                                                  child: Image.file(
                                                    imageFile!,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  )))),
                                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      Form(
                                          key: _formKey,
                                          child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                              widthFactor: 0.2,
                                              heightFactor: 0.4,
                                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                                TextFormField(
                                                    controller: _heightTextController,
                                                    focusNode: _focusHeight,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                        hintText: "Height",
                                                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                                        ))),
                                                SizedBox(height: 8.00),
                                                TextFormField(
                                                    controller: _widthTextController,
                                                    focusNode: _focusWidth,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      hintText: "Width",
                                                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
                                                InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Results');
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/submit.png'))), width: 100, height: 100, child: Container()))
                                              ])))
                                    ]))))))));
  }

  _getFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  /// Get from Camera
  _getFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what the error looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNxbl.png)

Comment: Are you launching a debug build? The red error screen gets replaced by a grey empty screen in non-debug builds. If that's the case, you should see an error in the console as well. Let us know the exact error so we're able to help

Comment: @dumazy thank you for your reply, the error is unexpected null value

Comment: Please edit your question and add which line/value is getting this null pointer error

Comment: I see you are using '!' on imageFile, which might still be null at the moment of the initial build. Only show the Image widget if imageFile is not null. You can use a inline if statement for that

Comment: @dumazy I edited the original answer with a full screenshot, please look at it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a null pointer on `imageFile`, wrap the `Image.file()` widget in an if statement

```
child: imageFile != null ? Image.file(
    imageFile!,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ) : null,
```